# in case vs. lest

Tags: conjunctions

I know there are quite a few threads about *in case* vs. *lest*, but I think none has seriously questioned the presumed interchangeability of the following:

1. Take an umbrella with you in case it rains.
2. Take an umbrella with you lest it (should) rain.

1 is definitely idiomatic, but 2, according to the dictionary definition of *lest*, seems problematic, even though some native speakers regard it correct, however uncommon *lest* is.

*lest* means "so as to prevent something from happening." (The other use basically means "that" and is used following adjectives denoting fear, worry, etc., and is outside the scope of the present discussion.)

But having an umbrella with you will not prevent the rain from happening. If so, would you still consider the use of *lest* in 2 correct?

Comment: The word ***lest*** is [becoming increasingly uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lest&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clest%3B%2Cc0) (particularly in *spoken* contexts), so I wouldn't spend too much time worrying about how to use it. Partly *because* it's a dated usage, you may see it with the equally old-fashioned ***subjunctive*** verb form *(lest it rain)*. But native speakers don't like the subjunctive much, so often we'd either "disguise" it with ***should***, or substitute an inflected verb *(**rains**, in your case).*

Comment: What you are 'preventing' when you take your umbrella is not the rain but implicitly your getting wet as a consequence of the rain.

Comment: Note that your definition **lest** = *so as to **prevent** something from happening* is just ***one*** way of summing up what the word means, and how it can be used. The full OED has in its first definition *introducing a clause expressive of something to be prevented **or guarded against***.

Comment: What @Fumble said about disguising it with *should* (or *normal* present or past tenses) I believe is restricted to BrE. In AmE, the subjunctive is much more frequently used: it remains in fixed phrases as neutral, and in other constructions as neutral/formal.

Comment: @userr2684291  American or otherwise, these days anyone who feels comfortable using "lest" in ordinary conversation is reasonably likely to throw in the "should" for extra pompousness.  I know **I** would.  :)

Comment: @Andrew I don't think *should* sounds that pompous in BrE as it does in AmE, in fact, it's a standard substitution for the subjunctive (as far as I know and from what I've heard/seen).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pick out one definition from one dictionary and call it "the" dictionary definition. Here we should insist on the indefinite article there.

For some 800 years now, and more, the word **lest** has been used to mean "for fear that" something will happen or "to guard against" something happening.

> You'd better tie a double knot in that lest it come undone.
>
> You'd better set your alarm, lest you oversleep.

Comment: Both of your examples are irrelevant, as they are instances of the (unquestionable) sense of "so as to prevent something."

Comment: @Apollyon: Why are you insisting that we take its meaning as "prevent" in your rain example?  It's not my answer that is irrelevant but your question. "But having an umbrella with you will not prevent the rain from happening. If so, would you still consider the use of lest in 2 correct?"

Comment: The examples are irrelevant, as they concern a sense of lest that is not under discussion.

Comment: The relevant sense of lest is, as  FumbleFingers rightly pointed out, "so as to guard against something," But your examples belong to the sense "so as to prevent something."

Comment: @Apollyon:  Your question asks whether **lest** is incorrectly used with rain because we cannot prevent the rain. But why does your mind even go there when one of the valid meanings is "for fear that it rain"?  Why focus on the meaning that does not apply to the situation when another meaning does apply?

Comment: FumbleFingers has offered the right sense already. But your examples are irrelevant. You're simply not understanding. At first, I didn't find the proper definition, but now that FumbleFingers has offered it, why did you give irrelevant  examples that fail to illustrate the proper sense?

Comment: I am giving examples that show the meaning "for fear that" shading into "to guard against".   We can be afraid that it will rain and do something in light of that fear, even though we cannot *prevent* the rain.

Comment: I'm afraid that "for fear that" is also irrelevant, as it means "to avoid the risk of ."

Comment: I'm afraid we had different senses of the relevant. You propose an irrelevant meaning, call it "the" meaning, and then ask whether native speakers are thus wrong in their using a word for 800 years now.  I propose a relevant meaning that applies to your rain scenario and you dismiss it as irrelevant.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by **if so** in "But having an umbrella with you will not prevent the rain from happening. If so, would you still consider the use of lest in 2 correct?"

Comment: If the OED is correct, does "for fear that" in the sense of "to avoid the risk of" apply in the original #2?

Comment: Didn't I tell you that at first, I didn't find the proper definition? So I asked that question. Now I know the proper definition, but you offered irrelevant examples and an irrelevant sense that doesn't apply to #2 in the OP.

Comment: Can you answer my question about **if so**?

Comment: That's just an inference based on an inadequate definition.

Comment: Can you tell me whether "for fear that" apply to #2 in the OP?

Comment: It depends on what we mean by **fear**, I fear.